# How to convert Date to nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, ibatis

[image]
have a search screen and I want to show results by searching specific data.My Filter is "show all date after '7/5/05' date".

As this is a JSF form, so **7/5/05** gets stored as Date.And again this is getting converted to Long as **'1120501800000'**.

Now the query becomes like this

```
SELECT * FROM   ABC  WHERE  due_date BETWEEN '1120501800000' AND '1952498291808'  ORDER  BY trstart_date DESC
```

But the problem is that due_date column is of **"nvarchar(50)"** , and values are stored as "7/5/05".

Can someone please tell me how can  I convert "1120501800000" to "7/5/05".Even I dont know what is **fastTime** as shown in image?

Thanks in advance.

I am using Jsf,Spring,IBatis,sql server

Comment: I'd look at correcting your schema so that due_date was stored as a date(time) rather than continuing to work with strings. Is `7/5/05` the 7th of May, 5th of July, or 5th of May (of some year ending with 7).

Comment: Date format is "m/dd/yyyy" in DB.

Comment: He's saying that you shouldn't store dates as strings. If you were to store them as datetimes or dates, then they wouldn't actually have a format, they would only have a value, and the formatting would only come into play when you try to display the date or convert it to a string.

Comment: If you *do* manage to convert to text, you'll start getting fun results, such as `7/15/05` being between `7/1/05` and `7/3/05` - because you'll be getting string comparisons, not date comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers seem to represent unix timestamps, with millisecond precision.

```
SELECT DATEADD( SECOND
              , CONVERT(BIGINT, '1120501800000') / 1000
              , '1970/01/01')
```

This converts to 2005/07/04 (`yyyy/mm/dd`), at 18:30.

In your example, you get 2005/07/05, which may be due to a UTC timezone offset in your local time. Let's say you're 6 hours ahead; that translates to:

```
SELECT DATEADD( HOUR
              , 6
              , DATEADD( SECOND
                       , CONVERT(BIGINT, '1120501800000') / 1000
                       , '1970/01/01')
              )
```

This converts to 2005/07/05, as you would expect.

To get the `mm/dd/yy` formatting you pretend:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, date)) + '/'
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, date))   + '/'
     + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, date)), 2)
  FROM ( SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 6, DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(BIGINT, '1120501800000') / 1000, '1970/01/01'))
       ) AS T (date)
```